# How align widgets with tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, widget, alignment

I have a basic GUI but some elements I can't align in the correctly side, I created 3 frames to organize the information that I need:

- First frame, I want to align the widgets to the left side.
- Second frame, I want that the title is near to the search box

This my code:

```
    # ============ frame_left ============

    # configure grid layout (1x8)
    self.frame_left.grid_rowconfigure(0, minsize=10)
    self.frame_left.grid_rowconfigure(5, weight=1)
    self.frame_left.grid_rowconfigure(8, minsize=20)

    self.label_1 = ctk.CTkLabel(master = self.frame_left, text = 'DATA:', text_font = ('Arial Greek', 15, 'bold'))
    self.label_1.grid(row = 1, column = 0, padx = 10, pady = 20, sticky = 'w')

    self.label_2 = ctk.CTkLabel(master = self.frame_left, text = f'- NUMBER: {App.no_var}', text_font = ('Arial Greek', 12))
    self.label_2.grid(row = 2, column = 0, padx = 0, pady = 20, sticky = 'w')

    self.label_3 = ctk.CTkLabel(master = self.frame_left, text = f'- ID: {App.id_var}', text_font = ('Arial Greek', 12))
    self.label_3.grid(row = 3, column = 0, padx = 10, pady = 20, sticky = 'w')

    self.label_3 = ctk.CTkLabel(master = self.frame_left, text = f'- PDF: {App.pdf_var}', text_font = ('Arial Greek', 12))
    self.label_3.grid(row = 4, column = 0, padx = 20, pady = 20, sticky = 'w')

    self.label_4 = ctk.CTkLabel(master = self.frame_left, text = 'FRAN VR', text_font = ('Arial Greek', 15, 'bold'))
    self.label_4.grid(row = 9, column = 0, padx = 10, pady = 20, sticky = 'w')
```

[image: This my basic GUI]

Comment: Please only ask about one question at a time. Either focus on the alignment issue, or the scrollbar issue, but not both.

Comment: Think carefully why you set those `padx` and `pady` to those values which causes the alignment issue you ask.

Comment: @BryanOakley ok understood.